# SelectedItem in DataGrid MVVM Light

Tags: wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, selecteditem

I have problem with binding SelectedItem in DataGrid(WPF Toolkit). When I open UserControl from main form SelectedItem don't displayed in DataGrid. But if to look in a debugger, there everything is allright, and selecteditem has some value. Then for example if I again setting   value SelectedItem (in code), DataGrid starts to displayed SelectedItem correctly.

Here is the part of my Code:

DictionaryView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="AccountingCatridge.Views.DictionaryView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" 
         xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Dictionary}">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" />
    <my:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                 Height="247" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="0,53,0,0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="300" 
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDictionaryItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 HeadersVisibility="None">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="50" Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>

    </my:DataGrid>
    <ToolBarTray Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,27,0,0" Name="toolBarTray1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" IsLocked="True">
        <ToolBar>
            <ToolBar.Items>
                <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddElementCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditElementCommand}"/>
                <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteElementsCommand}"/>
            </ToolBar.Items>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</Grid>
```

DictionaryViewModel

```
public DictionaryRecord SelectedDictionaryItem
{
    get { return _selectedDictionaryItem; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedDictionaryItem == value) return;
        _selectedDictionaryItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDictionaryItem");
    }

}

public IEnumerable<DictionaryRecord> DataItems
{
    get { return _dataItems; } 
    set
    {
        if (_dataItems == value) return;
        _dataItems = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("DataItems");
        SelectedDictionaryItem = _dataItems.First();
    }
}

public DictionaryViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
    Messenger.Default.Register<ShowDictionaryMessage>(this, ShowDictionary);
}

private void ShowDictionary(ShowDictionaryMessage mes)
{
    _typeDict = mes.TypeDict;
    Title = StringEnum.GetStringValue(_typeDict);

    switch (_typeDict)
    {
        case TypeDictionary.Employees:
            DataItems = _dataService.GetEmployees();
            break;
        case TypeDictionary.ModelPrinters:
            DataItems = _dataService.GetPrinters();
            break;
    }
}
```

it is a little more code and images.

```
    public RelayCommand EditElementCommand
        {
            get { return _editElementCommand ?? (_editElementCommand = new RelayCommand(EditElement)); }
        }

        private void EditElement()
        {
            if (SelectedDictionaryItem == null) return;
            Messenger.Default.Send(new ShowDictionaryRecordMessage{ Action = TypeRecordAction.Edit, Dictionary = _typeDict, Record = SelectedDictionaryItem});
        }

public RelayCommand SomeSimpleCommand
        {
            get { return _someSimpleCommand ?? (_someSimpleCommand = new RelayCommand(SomeSimpleAction)); }
        }

        private void SomeSimpleAction()
        {
            SelectedDictionaryItem = _dataItems.Last();
        }
```

here that I see when opening form

[image: ........]

but SelectedDictionaryItem has value and if I pressed "edit" the form with data necessary for me opens correctly.

if I execute SomeSimpleCommand. I see the following

[image: ........]

I need to know why in the first case I don't see a dark blue line for the SelectedItem.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: just edited my response now I can see what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dit:
Ok - can see what you're trying to do now...

I've had a similar problem in the past, although that was with a 3rd party control. I think what I was experiencing was that the Selected item was being set before the data was loaded in the grid.

I ended up having to do a little fudge, with a bit of code behind on the data loaded event of the grid. vm is a module level variable that stores reference to the ViewModel - alternatively you could get that by this.DataContext as ViewModel since you seem to use the locator to get yours :

```
 private void CaseGridView_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        var grid = sender as GridView; 
        if (grid != null) 
        { 
            grid.SelectedItem = vm.CurrentlySelectedItem; 
        } 
    }
```

One other thing worth trying is UpdateLayout() to make sure it refreshes